# Foreach Nested Loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested-loops

So here is my code. The problem I am having is that I want the number from HP in my PHP code into my HP HTML code and the same thing with Cylinders. I have figured out the other stuff but when it comes to that part I am stuck

```
<?php 

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $cars = array(
        array(
            "car"       =>  "Ferrari",
            "model"     =>  "Testarossa",
            "gearbox"   =>  "Manual 5 Shift",
            "designer"  =>  "Battista Pininfarina",
            "engine"    => 
        array(
            "HP"        => 390, 
            "Cylinders" => 12
            ),
        ),

    );

    ?>

    <?php foreach($cars as $cars_key => $car_val): ?>

        <ul>
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <li><b>Car:</b> <?php echo $car_val["car"]; ?></li>
                <li><b>Model:</b> <?php echo $car_val["model"]; ?></li>
                <li><b>Gearbox:</b> <?php echo $car_val["gearbox"]; ?></li>
                <li><b>Designer:</b> <?php echo $car_val["designer"]; ?></li>
                <li><b>Engine</b></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><b>HP:</b></li>            
                        <li><b>Cylinders:</b></li>                                        
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: How it looks now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few concerns:

1. You lose the brilliance/utility of an associative array when you hardcode values into your script that you could otherwise just call from the array.
2. I don't like the look of the mid-list `<div>`.  I can't think of any good reason to break up your unorder list flow with it.
3. I don't like the floating sub-list either.  It logically belongs to `Engine` and good markup would dictate that the sub-list exist inside of its parent.

Here is what I would suggest considering my above points...

*Some Notes:

- I'm not sure how you want to layout multiple lists as your array grows in size.
- The echoing is just my personal preference.  You can bounce in and out of php if you like.
- `ucfirst()` allows you to avoid hardcoding the keys.
- My snippet will make your task clean, DRY, and concise.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/34S23))

```
$cars = array(
            array(
                "car"       =>  "Ferrari",
                "model"     =>  "Testarossa",
                "gearbox"   =>  "Manual 5 Shift",
                "designer"  =>  "Battista Pininfarina",
                "engine"    =>  array(
                                    "HP"        => 390, 
                                    "Cylinders" => 12
                                )
            )
        );

foreach($cars as $details){
    echo "<ul style=\"margin-bottom:10px;\">";
        foreach($details as $key=>$item){
            echo "<li><b>",ucfirst($key),":</b>";
            if(!is_array($item)){
                echo " $item</li>";
            }else{
                    echo "<ul>";
                        foreach($item as $subkey=>$subval){
                            echo "<li><b>$subkey:</b> $subval</li>";
                        }
                    echo "</ul>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Source Code Output:

```
<ul style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <li><b>Car:</b> Ferrari</li>
    <li><b>Model:</b> Testarossa</li>
    <li><b>Gearbox:</b> Manual 5 Shift</li>
    <li><b>Designer:</b> Battista Pininfarina</li>
    <li><b>Engine:</b>
        <ul>
            <li><b>HP:</b> 390</li>
            <li><b>Cylinders:</b> 12</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Rendered Output:  (run my snippet @ phptester.net to see this)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that mickmackusa, I agree with you, it's better not to hardcode the values into the script. I like this version alot, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

From you example, it seems to me that the list is static and consists of two elements, then you need not use `forEach` at all.

```
<?php foreach($cars as $cars_key => $car_val): ?>
    <ul>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <li><b>Car:</b> <?php echo $car_val["car"]; ?></li>
            <li><b>Model:</b> <?php echo $car_val["model"]; ?></li>
            <li><b>Gearbox:</b> <?php echo $car_val["gearbox"]; ?></li>
            <li><b>Designer:</b> <?php echo $car_val["designer"]; ?>
            </li>
            <li><b>Engine</b></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><b>HP:</b><?php echo $car_val["engine"]["HP"]; ?></li>            
                    <li><b>Cylinders:</b><?php echo $car_val["engine"]["Cylinders"]; ?></li>                                        
                </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you do need to use a nested `forEach`, here is how you would go about doing that:

```
foreach($cars as $cars_key => $car_val):
  if($cars_key == "engine")
      foreach($car_val["engine"] as $engine_key => $engine_val):
        echo $engine_key.$engine_val;
      endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: I was going to add more cars and different information about them so thats why I wanted it to be dynamic, plus I am practicing all different kinds of loops with foreach. Doing as many nested loops as I can